# Pycharm Configurations--is there a way to configure a universal one?

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

So I use pycharm to produce my code and was wondering if there's a way to configure a default, universal interpreter, rather than having to configure a new one for every batch of code I work on, seeing as I have had to configure nearly 5/6 of them so far ...

[Screenshot if Interpretrers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/403Mb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File | New Projects Setup | Preferences for New Projects (Settings for New Projects on Windows).
Select Python Interpreter settings.